# Seeying up and down vote count on your own answer

Tags: discussion

It is a privilige to see those counts. But as with commenting on your own question, won't it be nice to see it with the votes too, so you have more insight behind the voting behaviour? Maybe with how manny, not who, on close votes?

Without it you can (mostly) never now what and why.

Edit:
There is an essential difference between -5 and -10 + 5. Some people only down-vote because they can down-vote and it can, but not limited to, triggered by a low rep. Ofcourse a bad-question is a bad-question.

Edit 2:
It's just a matter of seeing data and you can determine by that what is possibly wrong (or right). Consider this: +100 - 52. It would mean a real good question with a score of +48. However 52 said the oposite, that's a large number.

Comment: Other than your curiosity, is there any real benefit to seeing this? An answer that is -10 +5 is still a terrible answer at -5 regardless of what the vote count says.

Comment: @slugster: It is about interpreting different data and being able to predict why. Static data is nothing.

Comment: I honestly don't see any kind of improvement to SO coming from this.... Not saying it'll hurt SO, but I fail to see how it would help, so I'd prefer to have devs spend time on stuff that are more important

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason the limitation is there is because the query is expensive. We don't want a whole bunch of people doing it.

I could see a *lower* bar (say, 100 rep?) for your own questions, but if its a 1 rep user, they could just spam the button to put load on the server.

That said, its a pretty low bar as it stands, so I don't see a lot of value in optimizing for this case.

Comment: See your point, a minimal rep would be cool by me. However 35 fits fine (my current rep). 100 is fine though.

Comment: But what do you mean by spam the button, Do you need to enable it?

Comment: @Ruijter I'm saying a malicious user who just signed up (1 rep) could answer a question (or ask one), hit the "split" button, refresh, hit it again, etc. I'm sure someone would figure out how to automate the whole process. In other words, it just being on your own questions doesn't really protect us against the expensive operation being overused without a rep requirement as well.

Comment: Asking it for my own question/answer is just that. Keeping it as a privilige as it is now. Just didn't knew you had to hit the "split" since I can't yet.

Comment: @Ruijter your own question is the one place where you probably don't need it.  All you need to do is count the +5 votes and subtract the -2 votes, and that is your vote split.

Comment: Never thought of that one. I'll up you for that.

Comment: @Ruijter Just so you know, the "Split" button is actually the count itself. It becomes clickable at 1000 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

psubsee2003 pointed out that you can count the ups and downs at your own provile. That suits just fine.